# I get this error when I'm importing useContext

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

so when import using useContxt I get the error Server Error
ReferenceError: UserContext is not defined.
Notice that am using next.js. is it something to do with webpack or there is something in my code.

//////////////

```
===========parent component==============

import { useState, createContext } from "react";
import ArtSelctions from '../components/Gallery/ArtSelctions';
import {servicesLineOne,servicesLineTwo,servicesLineThree, liberatedT} from '../components/Gallery/artData';
import Viewmore from '../components/Viewmore';
import galleryStyle from '../styles/gallery.module.scss';

// to be continued where we will be using context to monunt the objects to our disered distination. 


 export const UserContext = createContext()

const Gallery = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('am the user');
   console.log(user)
  return (
 
     <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
                <div className={galleryStyle.container}>
                  <ArtSelctions {...props.liberatedT}  user={user} />
                </div>

                <div className={galleryStyle.container}>
                    <ArtSelctions {...props.servicesLineOne}/> 
                </div>
              <Viewmore  servicesLineTwo={props.servicesLineTwo}/>  
     </UserContext.Provider>
 

  )
}
export async function getStaticProps(){
      return {
        props: {
          liberatedT:liberatedT,
          servicesLineOne:servicesLineOne,  
          servicesLineTwo:servicesLineTwo,
          servicesLineThree:servicesLineThree, 
        }
      }
}
```

export default Gallery ;

==================Child component==============
This is the child component.

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import ServiCard from './artCard';
import SelctionStyle from '../../styles/selctions.module.scss';

   

const ArtSelctions = ({
        cards, 
}) => {


   const user = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <>
        <div className={SelctionStyle.selctionContainer}>
         
          
                <div className={SelctionStyle.selctionDiv}>
                {
                (cards || []).map(
                        card => {
             return <ServiCard key={card.id} {...card}> </ServiCard>
                        })
            }
                  
                </div>
        </div>
           
    </>
  )
}
export default ArtSelctions;
```

Comment: I did that in the parent component.

Comment: You are not importing UserContext from parent component. Please refer the answer suggested below and you will get your doubt clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create context first and then wrap your component within that context and then you can call/use that context in it's child component.
Refer [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) for using the context.
It's basically like Global Store (Mini Redux Store).

Basic Code Snippet for creating context:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

// @ts-ignore
export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

You use this as parent wrapper/element. This will let you use the context in it's child component i.e. `<App />`

```js
<StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
   <App />
</StateProvider>
```

Comment: in useContext we need to pass `createContext` also. Which you are passing but you are not importing it from where it's declared. So it's better you define `useContext` in same file where you are defining `createContext` and export `useContext(UserContext)` from your parent component so you can directly import it rather than importing `useContext` and `UserContext` in every file. I hope it's clear